I am seeing scroller end and scroller start in my fire fox browser

I am not able to understand if this will stay like this always.When i used scroll trigger. I am not able to remove the mark ,it is also not present in the file and no error is thrown in the console . Can anyone make me understand this .

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
